# Log In Activity In android

Tags: android, authentication

I have create a android application.in this application I have made the web services in php to fetch and store the data FROM  server side.my services run successfully and shows log cat message that log in successful. but when I click on login button on emulator.it display user name and pass word do not match.please tell me where I am wrong.

**Logcat**

```
// log cat message which shows log in is successful.it display the parameter With the added value that I have added into the database  


          D/response(2239):     "User_Detail": [
          D/response(2239):         {
             D/response(2239):             "license_pic": "upload\/license_45.png",
        D/response(2239):             "status": "0",
       D/response(2239):             "post_code": "0",
          D/response(2239):             "street_name": "tgwee",
             D/response(2239):             "authority_id": "6882",
             D/response(2239):             "id": "45",
           D/response(2239):             "first_name": "uruur",

          D/response(2239):             "Email": "viv@gmail.com",

          D/response(2239):             "State": "New South Wales",
             D/response(2239):             "face_pic": "upload\/face_45.png",
      D/response(2239):             "Suburb": "Sydney",
            D/response(2239):             "audit_card_pic": "upload\/audit_45.png",
          D/response(2239):             "unit_no": "6566555",
             D/response(2239):             "longitude": "",
            D/response(2239):             "add_count": "4",
           D/response(2239):             "latitude": "",
             D/response(2239):             "date_of_creation": "2014-06-18 09:19:27",
             D/response(2239):             "Surname": "hyee",
           D/response(2239):             "driving_lic": "58481",
            D/response(2239):             "mobile_no": "65494"
         D/response(2239):         }
            D/response(2239):     ],

            D/response(2239):     "message": "Login successful.",
             D/response(2239):     "err-code": "0"
               D/response(2239): }
```

**login code**

```
  public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    TextView newmember,forgot,view;
    Button submit,cancel;
    EditText uedit,pedit; 
    Vibrator vibe;
    String euid,epass;
    private String mfname,msname,mun,mstreet,msuburb,mstate,mpassword,mconfirm_password,mpostcode,mlicense,mid,mmobile,memail,mimagelicense,mauthcard,mpic,login_token,latitude,longitude;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    String name,pass;
    String status_key;
    private Typeface ftype;
    private static MyDialog dialog1;
    private static SuccessDialog dialog;
    private PasswordDB db;
    Bitmap bitmap1, bitmap2,bitmap3;
    Bitmap[] bitmap;
    String[] driver_details;
    private byte imageInByte1[],imageInByte2[],imageInByte3[] ;
    private Context mContext;
    private String mname,mobile,state,desc;

    public String advertisement_count;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

         vibe = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    //  ftype=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/Futura Koyu.ttf");
        uedit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.euname);
        pedit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.epassword);
        view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.forg);

        forgot= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.forget_password);
        cancel= (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        /* uedit.setTypeface(ftype);
        pedit.setTypeface(ftype);
        forgot.setTypeface(ftype);
        cancel.setTypeface(ftype); */
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent viewpass= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewData.class);
                startActivity(viewpass);
            }
        });

        newmember = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.newmemb);
        newmember.setTypeface(ftype);
        newmember.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Registration.class);
                startActivity(intt);
            }
        });
        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    //  submit.setTypeface(ftype);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

                        new SigIn(LoginActivity.this).execute();    
                        new Images().execute();
                    //  new ViewAdvertisement().execute();
            //  Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "You clicked the button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }       
           });


    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.relone);
            for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
                View view = group.getChildAt(i);
                if (view instanceof EditText) {
                    ((EditText)view).setText("");
                }
            }   }           

            });


    forgot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            vibe.vibrate(50);
            /*String rr="Im getting "+resdis+"% off at "+name1+" with Circl. You can too! Get it here: url="
                               + " http://yoz.io/r/sBxQ";*/


            String rr= "Im getting % off at with Circl. You can too! Get it here: url http://yoz.io/r/sBxQ";

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL , new String[]{""});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Circl Sharing");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , rr);
            try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            }

            }           

            });

    if(isInternetOn(LoginActivity.this)== false)
    {
    }
       }

    public boolean isInternetOn(Context ctx) {
        this.mContext = ctx;
        ConnectivityManager Connect_Manager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        State connected = NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
        State connecting = NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING;
        State disconnected = NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED;

        State info0 = Connect_Manager.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();
        State info1 = Connect_Manager.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();

        // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
        if (info0 == connected || info0 == connecting || info1 == connecting
                || info1 == connected) {

            Log.d("Internet", "Connected");
            return true;
        } else if (info0 == disconnected || info1 == disconnected) {
            Log.d("Internet", "DisConnected");
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

      private class SigIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
          private final Context _context;  

          public SigIn(Context context){
                _context = context;

            }
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @SuppressLint("WorldReadableFiles")
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
        {
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try 
                {
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait signing in...");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            pDialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                    JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
                    euid = uedit.getText().toString();
                    epass = pedit.getText().toString();

                    euid.replace("" ,"%20");
                    epass.replace("" ,"%20");
                    job.put("status_key","0");
                    job.put("method", "login");
                    job.put("email", euid);
                    job.put("password",epass );
                    job.put("login_token",login_token );

                /*
                    System.out.print("latitude is "+latitude);
                    job.put("latitude",latitude);
                    job.put("longitude",longitude);*/

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());

                    //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");
                     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/DGCapp/webservice.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(se);

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                      String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                      System.out.println("response "+data);

                      JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

                    Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));
                    if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                    {

                    JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");  
                    Log.d("Array", jArray.toString(4));
                    JSONObject adv= jo.getJSONObject("advertisement_count");  
                    advertisement_count=adv.getString("count(*)");
                    System.out.print("advertisemnet"+advertisement_count);              
                    for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        try {
                        JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                mfname = jsob.getString("first_name");
                                msname = jsob.getString("Surname");
                                mun = jsob.getString("unit_no");
                                mstreet = jsob.getString("street_name");
                                msuburb = jsob.getString("Suburb");
                                mstate = jsob.getString("State");
                                mpassword = jsob.getString("password");
                                mpostcode = jsob.getString("post_code");
                                mlicense = jsob.getString("driving_lic");
                                mid = jsob.getString("authority_id");
                                mmobile = jsob.getString("mobile_no");
                                memail = jsob.getString("Email");
                                login_token=jsob.getString("login_token");
                                mimagelicense=jsob.getString("license_pic");
                                mauthcard=jsob.getString("audit_card_pic");
                                mpic=jsob.getString("face_pic");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        } 

        pref=getSharedPreferences("Driver", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=pref.edit();

                    edit.putString("mfname", mfname);
                    edit.putString("msname", msname);
                    edit.putString("mun", mun);
                    edit.putString("mstreet", mstreet);
                    edit.putString("msuburb", msuburb);
                    edit.putString("mpassword", mpassword);
                    edit.putString("mpostcode", mpostcode);
                    edit.putString("mlicense", mlicense);
                    edit.putString("mid", mid);
                    edit.putString("mmobile", mmobile);
                    edit.putString("memail", memail);
                    edit.putString("login_token", login_token);

                    System.out.print("login_token in LoginActivity"+ login_token);
                    edit.putString("mimagelicense", mimagelicense);
                    edit.putString("mauthcard", mauthcard);
                    edit.putString("mpic", mpic);
                    edit.putString("advertisement_count", advertisement_count);
                    edit.commit();

                    //if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                    {
                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                        alert.setTitle("Login!!!");
                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) 
                            {

                            pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                dialog.dismiss();

                                Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                       startActivity(tabint);
                        }
                        });
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                alert.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                        alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",

                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                dialog.dismiss();

                            }
                        });
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                                pDialog.dismiss();

                                alert.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                alert.setMessage("No Internet connection ");
                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) 
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        alert.show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return params;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
        {

            LoginActivity test = (LoginActivity) _context;
            test.driver_details=result;
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }   
       }
       private class Images extends AsyncTask<Bitmap[],Bitmap,Bitmap[]> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(Bitmap[]...urls) {


            try {
                 bitmap1 = DownloadImage(mimagelicense);
                 bitmap2 = DownloadImage(mauthcard);
                 bitmap3= DownloadImage(mpic);
              ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                   imageInByte1 = stream.toByteArray();


                   System.out.print("DB storing image " + imageInByte1);           

                   bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                   imageInByte2 = stream.toByteArray();
                   bitmap3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                   imageInByte3 = stream.toByteArray();

            System.out.println(" ****************************");     

                    for(int i = 0; i < driver_details.length; i++) 
                       // System.out.println(driver_details[i]);
                    Log.v("Async variables",driver_details[i]);

                    db = new PasswordDB(getApplicationContext());               
                      db.insert(mfname, msname, mun, mstreet, msuburb,mstate, mpostcode, mlicense, mid, mmobile, memail,  imageInByte1, imageInByte2, imageInByte3);
                    /**
                    * CRUD Operations
                    * */
                    // Inserting Contacts

                    //db.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
            return bitmap;
        }   

        private  java.io.InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
        throws IOException
              {
              java.io.InputStream in = null;
              int response = -1;

            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                    
                throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

            try{
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();

                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                
                }                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)

            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                throw new IOException("Error connecting");           
            }
            return in;    
        }
        private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
        {       
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            java.io.InputStream in = null;       
            try {
                in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;               
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] result) 
        {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: this is the log cat message but my log in activity is not working.i am totally confused tell where i am wrong

Comment: add button click code also.

Comment: Without your code for handling Button Click, we won't be able to help.

Comment: can you please update your code so we can help you.

Comment: i have added the code please check that

Comment: i have added the code please check

Comment: the another logcat message is: 07-04 00:28:46.326: W/System.err(2239): org.json.JSONException: No value for driver_details
07-04 00:28:46.326: W/System.err(2239):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
07-04 00:28:46.336: W/System.err(2239):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
07-04 00:28:46.336: W/System.err(2239):  at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:455)

Comment: why so much code on sign in? u just wanna check success meassgae right?

Comment: yes i want to log in success....another code is for other purpose

Comment: ok plz help me to understand ur question, i could not find code to compare ur success message, on alert u r doing something but not comparing? what extatcly u wanna go on success of login?

Comment: actually the web services are made for compare the login message like:and the user email and pass is set in the services

Comment: log cat error is: 07-04 00:28:46.326: W/System.err(2239): org.json.JSONException: No value for driver_details

Comment: you must be doing JSON parsing using some sort of `CommonClass` and would have used it in your activity. the JSON parser would be logging those messages.

Comment: ok ur trying to get driver_details values whereas no such feild on json ..so u r getting such exception, try to solve th eexception and let me know if any issue